# Howto bypass checkout page completely and go straight to "place order"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to completely bypass the checkout page and go straight to "place order", which then redirects the customer to payment. I do not need to capture any billing details, and there is only 1 available payment method, so this intermediary page is not needed.

I've tried this code which is supposed to disable the billing address fields. This doesn't go far enough for what I want, however. I simply want the user to be redirected to payment.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_init','disable_billing');
function disable_billing($checkout){
  $checkout->checkout_fields['billing']=array();
  return $checkout;
  }
```

When I add this code to function.php, it actually does not do anything at all for some reason. Not sure if I am doing something incorrectly.

Any help or suggestions appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know.

```
add_filter('add_to_cart_redirect', 'lw_add_to_cart_redirect');
function lw_add_to_cart_redirect() {
 global $woocommerce;
 $lw_redirect_checkout = $woocommerce->cart->get_checkout_url();
 return $lw_redirect_checkout;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation! I tried adding this code to my functions.php file but unfortunately does not do anything. I wonder if maybe I am doing something incorrectly..

Comment: I should add that I already have a redirect setup, such that when someone "adds to cart", it redirects directly to checkout page, as there is no need for a shopping cart, there is only one product.